# How to consume a Java soap web service using Java app based on JDK 11

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, soap-client, wsimport

I created a web service with java, I've used jaxb and jax-ws annotations with the help of maven dependencies, I'd like to consume that web service with java application after some research I found that I should run a `wsimport` command to generate JAX-WS portable artifacts, however this command is no longer available in jdk 11 and above so where can i find the executable file and add it to my jdk bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can download JAXWS-RI zip distribution file from [the Maven repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/). I'm using version 2.3.3-b01 and works fine.

After download, you can symlink the `wsimport.sh` script to your PATH:

```
$ cd ~/bin # or other location in your path
$ ln -s /path/to/jaxws-ri-zip-contents/bin/wsimport.sh wsimport
```

Now you can call `wsimport` as a command.